# How to use the cpp-generated-code implementation of protobuf for python3?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I want to use protobuf, specifically the cpp-generated-code implementation for python. 
So far I have build protobuf3.7 in cpp with static linking, installed the python version with cpp_implementation, which usese the cpp-reflection implementation.

The starting point for the next step was this: [Fast, native-C Protocol Buffers from Python](https://yz.mit.edu/wp/fast-native-c-protocol-buffers-from-python/), which is for python2.
I ended up following [this guide on how to write cpython extension modules using C++](https://thomasnyberg.com/cpp_extension_modules.html) and trying to emulate what was done for [the benchmarks of protobuf.](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/benchmarks/python/python_benchmark_messages.cc) https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/benchmarks/python/py_benchmark.py and writing a **setup.py** for it:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('podpb', 
    include_dirs = ['C:\mydir\podpb\include'],
    libraries = ['libprotobuf', 'my_other_lib_static'],
    library_dirs = ['C:\mydir\podpb\lib', 
                    'C:\mydir\otherlib\install\lib'],
    sources = ['podpb.cpp'],
    extra_compile_args = ['/MT'],
    language='c++'
    #extra_link_args = ['-static']
    )

setup (name = 'ProtobufC',
   version = '0.1',
   packages = ['podpb'],
   #cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
   description = 'PB as a C module',
   ext_modules = [module1])
```

**podpb.cpp:**

```
#include <Python.h>

#include "my_headers.pb.h"
...

static PyMethodDef PodMethods[] = {
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "podpb",             /* m_name */
    "This is a module",  /* m_doc */
    -1,                  /* m_size */
    PodMethods,          /* m_methods */
    NULL,                /* m_reload */
    NULL,                /* m_traverse */
    NULL,                /* m_clear */
    NULL,                /* m_free */
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_podpb(void)
{
    my_namespace::my_class().descriptor();
    ...
    PyObject* m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
    return m;
}
```

I now have a podpb.cp36-win_amd64.pyd and a ProtobufC-0.1-py3.6.egg-info file and am trying to use it [like this](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/benchmarks/python/py_benchmark.py), simply by importing it (import podpb in my case, import libbenchmark_messages in the e.g.). In the example it is not used at all besides importing it.

[update @2019/03/25]
I use line_profiler to measure performance and I don't see any improvement when going from cpp-reflection to cpp-generated code. Here is the benchmark script:

```
import os
import podpb

def my_function(version):
    some_path = 'something3' if (version == 3) else 'something'
    this_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    data_path = os.path.join(this_path, '..', 'data', some_path)
    some_files = [x for x in os.listdir(data_path) if x.endswith('.bin')]
    skey = lambda x : int(x.split('.')[0].split('_')[1])

    some_packages = []
    for fname in sorted(some_files, key=skey):
        with open(os.path.join(data_path, fname), 'rb') as f:
            some_packages.append(b"".join(f.readlines()))
    return some_packages

@profile
def main():

    from some3.place  import SomeData as Data3
    some_files = my_function(3)
    o = Data3()

    N = 1000
    for i, some_msg in enumerate(some_files [:N]):
        o.ParseFromString(some_msg)
        print(i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Am I using this correctly?

[/update]